# Finding the normal to the edges in an image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, gradient, normals

I need to the normal (to the edge) at each point of the edges detected. I can't think of a good method to do this and my main concern isn't this. I need the normals to be consistent. What I mean is that they should all be outwards facing (or inwards). Consider the image (after edge detection)

[image]

Since it doesn't form a closed curve, I can't define inwards or outwards but what I want is that adjacent normals should not be opposite to each other. I am not sure whether saying that adjacent normals should form an acute angle is the right way to express this condition. Is there any known algorithm/library which addresses this problem?

Comment: Did you compute the edges from the grayscale image? If so, you can use cv::Sobel to get the derivatives and cv::phase to get the angle

Comment: Did you use Canny edge detector to get this result? Internally it uses the gradient (which points in the normal direction). I recommend that you read up on Canny, then implement it yourself or find an implementation that you can modify, and get the data you need from it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I will look it up!